# Confused about stacked tensor input to Multilayer perceptron in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mlp

I have an input sequence in the form **sequence_len x C x H x W** = [10, 3, 16, 16] (Assuming batch size = 1). These are 10 images stacked together in a torch tensor. I wish to pass this to an MLP and obtain the next 10 as predictions from the MLP.
The structure of MLP has one hidden layer with 32 units.
If I flatten the input from dimension 1 - [10, 768]

My current code looks like this:

```
class MLP3(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, ip_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(ip_layers, 32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(32, 32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(32, 10)
    )

    def forward(self, x):
        #forward
        return self.layers(x)
```

However, I am unable to pass the entire tensor and not sure how I can obtain 10 outputs from the MLP. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: I will be honest with you. You can't do this cause of tons of reasons. Some related to code and some related to your understanding of deep learning. So, before you try to implement it in code you should read about a lot of topics. Like `Convolutions`, `LSTMs`, `VAE`, `Temporal Coherence`, and much much more. Also, just to mention the problem you share is from a relatively advanced domain of deep learning.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I think this is possible, if I reshape the data as [batchsize*sequence_len, 3, 16, 16] process each input separately and obtain the required number of outputs. As the MLPs or CNNs do not care about the sequence as with the case of LSTMs or RNNs.

Comment: Yes, It is technically possible but when I said it's impossible I mean you can't get any results at all from doing this. But if you still want to do this then I will write an answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat the challenge here is, I have this MLP in between a CNN and an LSTM. And the LSTM requires a batch_size which led to confusion in the case of the MLP/ CNN

Answer (score 0):

To get 10 outputs at the end you have to use a multi-channel model. For that, you have to define the `base_model` in your `__init__` function and modify your other datasets and the forward function and write loss for every class. I will write a boilerplate for you

```
class SDataset(torch.nn.utils.Dataset):
  def __init__(self):
    ....
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    ....
    '''
    Till now everything was the same as before.
    Now the below thing is something that you have to change.
    '''
    outimg1 = self.image_seq[idx+1]
    outimg2 = self.image_seq[idx+2]
    .
    .
    outimg10 = self.image_seq[idx+10]

    return X, (outimg1, outimg2 ..... outimg10)
```

The model

```
class Predictor(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Predictor, self).__init__()
    self.base_model = somebasemodel
    self.out1 = # Takes input from base_model and output an image
    self.out2 = # ....
    .
    .
    self.out10 = # ...

  def forward(self, x):
    features = self.base_model(x)
    res1 = self.out1(features)
    .
    .
    res10 = self.out10(features)
    return res1, res2, .... res10
```

The training step

```
inputs, outputs = batch
preds = model(inputs)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss1 = criterion(preds[0], outputs[0])
.
.
loss10 = criterion(preds[9], outputs[9])
total_loss = loss1 + loss2 + ... + loss10
total_loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Now that was the most of it.

Comment: This isn't the most optimal way to do it, but thanks for your effort. Torch.nn.Linear accepts a tensor input and just by setting the right batch size, you can obtain the sequence in the output.